# How would one recreate Cloudflare's always online feature using nginx?

Tags: caching, nginx, memcached

Cloudflare uses nginx.

They have this feature called Always Online: http://www.cloudflare.com/always-online

As their website states:
Always Online is a feature that caches a static version of your pages in case your server goes offline.

I would like to setup a caching nginx server on the other side of the globe and have it cache my website's static files and point my secondary dns to it. If my website's server goes down, a cached version will be showed.

Is this possible to do using nginx reverse-proxy feature?

Or, I could also save a copy of all my static files including .html files in the nginx server, and have it load these files when the main server is offline.

Can nginx do this?

Answer (score 1):

In Nginx it is possible to set-up a caching. The documentation even provides [an example of a Nginx reverse proxy with caching](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/):

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path  /data/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m
    inactive=24h  max_size=1g;
    server {
        location / {
            proxy_pass             http://1.2.3.4;
            proxy_set_header       Host $host;
            proxy_cache            STATIC;
            proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
                                   http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `proxy_cache_use_stale` argument, in the example, in the event of a range of errors (including timeouts, 500, 502, 503, 504), then the old cached item is supplied.